# Is it possible for accessing Azure table service from data bricks

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, databricks

I have loaded data into the Azure table service. I would like to access the data from data bricks the same way we access data from Azure blob.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you can mark it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Azure Databricks does **not** support the data source of azure table storage.

For more details about the Data Sources of  Azure Databricks, refer to this [link](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/index.html).

[image]

Besides, if you want to improve Azure Databricks for it, you could post your idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks).

Answer (score 1):

I think the above answer is old - so here is my update.
I am currently accessing data from `Azure` Tables through `DataBricks` like this:

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService

table_service = TableService(account_name='accountX', 
account_key=None,sas_token="tokenX") #set Azure connection

data = table_service.query_entities('tableX') #read  
df_raw = pd.DataFrame([asset for asset in data]) #move it to pandas if you prefer
```

You need your own credentials for account_name and sas_token; TableX is the name of the table you want to access